# How to Print Invoice from WPF Controls

Tags: wpf, image, barcode-printing

I am creating a point-of-sale system in WPF. I want to print an invoice during completion of an order. Data will be provided from a TextBox for Invoice: `txtinvoices`, `txtQty`, `txtTotalPrice`, `txtAmountPaid` and `txtDate` are some textboxes I want to print on invoices. There is one barcode image as well for each order that is required to print on an invoice.

I am able to print everything using a flow document. But I'm unable to print this barcode image.

```
//InvoiceID Generate
txtInvoiceID.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("sMMHHmyyyydd" + userId);
//Barcode Generation
BarcodeEncoder enc = new BarcodeEncoder();
WriteableBitmap image = enc.Encode(BarcodeFormat.Code39, txtInvoiceID.Text);
barCodeImage.Source = image;
```

Can anyone help me with printing in WPF?

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head, use the code below (isn't tested).

```
//InvoiceID Generate
txtInvoiceID.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("sMMHHmyyyydd" + userId);
//Barcode Generation
BarcodeEncoder enc = new BarcodeEncoder();

System.Windows.Controls.Image imgBarCode = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
System.Drawing.Bitmap bm = enc.Encode(BarcodeFormat.Code39, txtInvoiceID.Text);  

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {               
   bm.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
   byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();
   Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
   imgBarCode.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
   } 

// do whatever you want with imgBarCode now.
```

Comment: I don't know why but it is giving me error 

Error:Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap' to 'System.Drawing.Bitmap'